# Eclipse - How to change Syntax Coloring of .jrxml file for JasperReports plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jasper-reports

How can I change the syntax coloring of .jrxml file when viewing the Source tab. I tried changing the editor for content type .jrxml but it removes the JasperSoft designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I just want to change the coloring of .jrxml file to be more readable while in dark mode, I just install the DevStyle the in the Marketplace.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for Jaspersoft Studio which doesn't have a marketplace?